# Replacing column name by dictionary value

Tags: python

I have dictionary with all keys in lowercase. I would like to replace column names with the dictionary value when dictionary key is found in column names. But the dictionary keys in column names are not all in lowercase. So I would like to be able to say "if dictionary key is found in columns, replace it by dictionary value. I have tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
df.columns = [col_dict.get(x, x) for x in df.columns.str.lower()]
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you give an example? To me it seems like you would just be replacing a column name with the same name -- so nothing happens....

Comment: example: col_dict= {('last name','family name') :'John'} and in the column name you can find 'Last Name', 'FAMILLY NAME'.

Comment: "FAMILLY" with two L's won't match "family" simply by making it lowercase, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in col_dict.items():
    for i in df.columns:
        col = str(i).lower()
        if k == col:
            df = df.rename(columns={i:v})
```

Where k is key of dictionary and v is the associated value.